# Дано натуральные число N (5 ≤ N ≤ 12)

Tags: python

Дано натуральные число N (5 ≤ N ≤ 12). Найти значение выражения:
(1/5)^N+(1/6)^N+(1/7)^N+...+1/N^N . Результат вывести в виде вещественного числа.
**Задачу нужно решить с помощью вложенных циклов.**
Вот мой код:

```
N = int(input("Введите N(5 <= N <= 12) => ")) 
s = 0 
if 5 <= N <= 12: 
    for i in range(5, N + 1): 
        s += (1/i) ** N 
    print("Значение выражения =>", s) 
else: 
    print("Вы ввели неправильное значение N")
```

Помогите исправить код и написать его с вложенными циклами. **Можно использовать только цикл While или for, списки и другие структуры данных использовать запрещено.**

Comment: Непонятно, зачем там ещё один цикл, если только один раз нужно вычислить. Имеющегося кода достаточно. Если нужно много раз вычислить для разных `N`, тогда сделайте снаружи ещё цикл `while True:`, например.

Answer (score 2):

На правильность не претендую, просто как вариант.

```
N = int(input("Введите N(5 <= N <= 12) => ")) 
s = 0 
if 5 <= N <= 12: 
     i = 5
     while i <= N:
         j = 1
         k = 1
         while j <= N:
             k *= i
             j += 1
         s += (1/k)
         i += 1
     print("Значение выражения =>", s)
else:
    print("Вы ввели неправильное значение N")
```

Comment: Выглядит правильно. Разве что циклы for при известном количестве итераций более подходят.

Comment: Про степень в виде цикла я то и не догадался ))